# The Poisson pmf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this the problem below, where I have to find the pmf.

Let $X \sim \mathcal{Poiss}(\lambda)$. Write down the pmf $p\text{x}$.

I know that a Poisson random variable has a PMF given by:  $P(X = x) = \frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!}$

So is this the answer to the problem, or am I missing something?

Comment: That's the answer. (You might also mention that $x$ is any nonnegative integer.)

Comment: The pmf is more correctly written as $$P(X=x)=\begin{cases}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}&,\text{ if }x=0,1,2,\ldots\\\quad0&,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}\quad,\,\lambda>0$$

Comment: As a nitpick, avoid using $x$ for a discrete valued random variable. $P(X=k)$ or $P(X=n)$ would be a more typically used notation. As mentioned, it's a nitpick.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have the correct equation for all nonnegative integer inputs of the PMF. However, you can improve your answer. A Poisson PMF with parameter $\lambda$ is more correctly written as:
$$
P(X = k) = \begin{cases}
\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{k}}{k!} & k = 0,1,2,...\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
It is also important to note that $\lambda > 0$.